# Why do we return a pointer not a value in this example?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"


type argError struct {
    arg  int
    prob string
}

func (e *argError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d - %s", e.arg, e.prob)
}

func f2(arg int) (int, error) {
    return -1, &argError{arg, "can't work with it"}
}

func main() {

    _, e := f2(42)
    if ae, ok := e.(*argError); ok {
        fmt.Println(ae.arg)
        fmt.Println(ae.prob)
    }
}
```

in f2 we have pointer **&argError...** as return value, but method declared to return **error**. Why f2 signature is not defined as

func f2(arg int) (int, ***error**) instead? Or why do we return pointer not a value in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

error is an interface that asks to have an `Error() string` method.

The problem here is that you declare the `Error() string` method on a pointer. `func (e *argError) Error() string`, thus only an `*argError` implements an `error`, but not an `argError`. So you can only return an `&argError{...}`.

You should know that `*error` and `error` of an pointer is different. The former is a pointer to an `interface` holding whatever concrete type and the latter is an `interface` holding a pointer.

In practice, since an `interface` is all about methods, a pointer to an `interface` is rarely useful while an `interface` holding a pointer is widely used.